# Как писать юнит-тесты на новый код в монолитном методе?

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты, рефакторинг

Есть огромный метод F c бизнес логикой покрытой тестами.

```
public ValidationResult F(...)
{...}
```

Добавил еще немного:

```
if(...)
{ 
 ...
 Repository.UpdateSomeDataInDB(...);
 ...
}
```

Задача: Нужно написать unit тесты на новую логику.

Вопросы:

1. Была мысль написать отдельный метод F2 для новой логики.
   Но эта логика не используется больше нигде, следовательно F2 - приватный метод. Нужно ли писать на приватные методы тесты?
2. Метод F уже очень большой и названия тестов для описания условий огромные и сами тесты становятся большими. Но слышал что тесты должны быть простыми. Что делать в таком случае?

Comment: Для начала - не писать новую логику, а (раз у вас это уже покрыто тестами) провести рефакторинг, раздробив огромный метод F на серию мелких.

Comment: Серия мелких будут приватными и мой новый тоже, верно? Тесты нужны на приватные?

Comment: Ваш вопрос потенциально неплох, но в текущем виде недостаточно проработан и его нужно закрыть. Вообще для метки инспекция кода не хватает главного - самого кода. Так, видим, какие-то фрагменты кода, остальное словами описывается "у меня методы станут приватными". Код это должен сказать читателю, а не вы. Извините, но метка "инспекция-кода" не к месту, убираю.

Comment: Код не мой, показывать нельзя. По стилю методы которые используем только внутри класса - приватные.

Comment: Создайте маленькое рабочее приложение, в котором можете использовать другую предметную область (всё равно же будут репозитории), которое не попадёт под NDA, продумайте как оставить самое существенное и чтобы кода было поменьше. Я вот постоянно на трёх классах (Order, OrderPosition, Product) показываю многие вещи, а недавно договорился до того, что ради хохмы в следующий раз на программе для составления гороскопов буду показывать (это вообще не имеет никакого отношения к кровавому энтерпрайзу, в котором работаю)

Comment: ок, подумаю как показать хороший пример, спасибо!

Comment: По сути. Приватные методы не тестируют - это общепринятый подход в отрасли. Но. Если у вас класс с одним-единственным публичным огромным методом F (и парой десятков приватных) - то у вас практически наверняка будет возможность раздробить класс на серию более мелких классов. И тестами уже покрыто, лафа - самое время взяться за рефакторинг.

Comment: Действие одно, одно нажатие кнопки пользователя. Интерфейс предоставляет одно действие - один публичный метод. Но нужно учитывать состояние по 100500 параметрам(базы, клиента), поэтому много логики внутри. Думаю отдельные классы - выход. Спасибо!